# Quicksort Partition Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I am having some trouble with my quicksort. Here is my program:

```
def main():
     Array = [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 10]
     right_index = (len(Array) - 1)
     left_index = 0
     Quicksort(Array, left_index, right_index)

def Quicksort(Array, left_index, right_index):
    if len(Array) == 1:
        return Array
    pivot_index = Partition(Array, left_index, right_index)
    Quicksort(Array, left_index, pivot_index-1)
    Quicksort(Array, pivot_index + 1, right_index)
    return Array

def Partition(Array, left_index, right_index):
    pivot = Array[left_index]
    i = left_index + 1
    for j in range(left_index + 1, right_index):
        if Array[j] <= pivot:
            Array[j], Array[i] = Array[i], Array[j]
            i += 1
    Array[left_index], Array[i - 1] = Array[i - 1], Array[left_index]
    return i - 1

main()
```

Am I doing something wrong? I get the error: `for j in range(left_index + 1, right_index)`:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison".`

Thanks for any assistance anyone out there may have.

Comment: face think for base case in Quicksort function

Comment: I added a statement before calling partition, to make sure left_index was always less than right index so it didn't recursively call forever, is that correct?

Though now I'm getting the error: 
    Array[left_index], Array[i-1] = Array[i-1], Array[left_index]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: buddy you're missing th point that len(Array) will never reduce in the way you're calling function.

Comment: Could you be a little more elaborate? I apprecate your help, I'm sorry and relatively new to recursive algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a recursion error, there's usually something wrong with your termination condition. (That's what moghya was trying to tell you, albeit not very clearly.) In your case:

```
if len(Array) == 1:
    return Array
```

You use two indices to keep track of which subarray you are currently treating. The base array `Array` will always have a length of 11; the only changes you make to that array is to swap elements around. Therefore, your termination condition should be:

```
if left_index >= right_index:
    return Array
```

There is another mistake in your code: When you partition your array, you miss out on the last element. Here:

```
for j in range(left_index + 1, right_index):
```

the upper bound should be `right_index + 1`. This off-by one error was probably introduced because you chose to use an inclusive upper bound, that is `right_index` is the last valid index.

This is not how Python (and many other languages) handle arrays. Python arrays and ranges have an inclusive lower bound and an exclusive upper bound. Zero-based indices and exclusive upper bound seem a bit conterintuitive at first, but I suggest that you embrace rather than fight this convention.

I also suggest that you write a wrapper quicksort function that doesn't require passing in the array bound explicitly. Putting all this together, you get:

```
def main():
     Array = [10, 5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 9, 2, 1, 10]
     quicksort(Array)

     print Array

def quicksort(a):
    quicksort_sort(a, 0, len(a))
    return a

def quicksort_sort(a, left, right):
    if left + 1 < right:
        ipivot = quicksort_part(a, left, right)    
        quicksort_sort(a, left, ipivot)
        quicksort_sort(a, ipivot + 1, right)

def quicksort_part(a, left, right):
    pivot = a[left]
    i = left + 1

    for j in range(left + 1, right):
        if a[j] <= pivot:
            a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
            i += 1

    a -= 1
    a[left], a[i] = a[i], a[left] 

    return i

main()
```

Comment: Very informative thank you, heading to sleep and reading this on my phone but I’m pretty sure that cleared up my confusions, cheers

Comment: I'd suggest editing your code since you have a type error when you try to decrease the array by 1, I believe what you're trying to do is``` i -= 1``` instead of ```a -= 1```